# Get text/description for a word using web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am building a text classification model and at times some words are out of vocabulary(OOV) words. These words can be company names, could be a slang or just be incorrectly typed or something else altogether.

To improve the performance of my text classification model, I need to find a description/text/articles containing these OOV words using web scraping.

From my limited experience with web scraping, I understand that I can do it if I already know what website I need to scrape from. How do I go about looking for description/text/articles for a specific word without having a specific website in mind?